# How to configure the import path in Visual Studio IronPython projects

Tags: python, visual-studio, ironpython, ironpython-studio

I have built the IronPythonIntegration solution that comes with the Visual Studio 2005 SDK (as explained at http://www.izume.com/2007/10/13/integrating-ironpython-with-visual-studio-2005), and I can now use IronPython projects inside Visual Studio 2005. However, to let a Python file import from the standard library I need to include these two lines first:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:\Python24\lib')
```

and similarly for any other folders I want to be able to import from.

Does anyone know a way to set up import paths so that all IronPython projects automatically pick them up?

Comment: Hey Charles, did you find a way to make this work with the latest IronPython studio?

Comment: I've done very little with IronPython for a while now. (It's on a long list of projects I'd like to find some time for one day.) Which version of IronPythonStudio do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Set the environment variable IRONPYTHONPATH in your operating system to 'c:\Python24\lib'. (Or anywhere else you need).

Comment: I've done that already. It works in the ipy.exe shell, but has no effect in Visual Studio.